# React Native v0.42 flexbox error in ScrollView

Tags: android, ios, react-native, flexbox, scrollview

My React Native render code is:

```
<ScrollView
  contentContainerStyle={{
    minHeight: 100,
    flexDirection: "column",
    alignItems: "stretch",
    marginTop: 16,
  }}
  alwaysBounceVertical={false}
  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
>
    <View style={{flex: 0.5, backgroundColor: "green"}}>
        <View style={{height: 10, backgroundColor: "yellow"}}/>
    </View>
    <View style={{flex: 0.5, backgroundColor: "blue"}}/>
</ScrollView>
```

The code above should render 2 views, of height 50 each, top one green and bottom one yellow. Inside the top view, there should be a yellow view of height 10.

Instead, it renders the top view with height 60 and bottom box with height 50. The top box has a box inside with height 10. The colours are all correct.

However, if I change the height:10 part to height:"20%", it works all fine.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either position your yellow view absolutely:

```
<ScrollView
  contentContainerStyle={{
    minHeight: 100,
    flexDirection: "column",
    alignItems: "stretch",
    marginTop: 16,
  }}
  alwaysBounceVertical={false}
  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
>
  <View style={{flex: 0.5, backgroundColor: "green"}}>
    <View style={{
      height: 10, 
      backgroundColor: "yellow", 
      position: 'absolute',
      top: 0, left: 0, right: 0 
    }}/>
  </View>
  <View style={{flex: 0.5, backgroundColor: "blue"}}/>
</ScrollView>
```

or use a fixed height on the ScrollView:

```
<ScrollView
  contentContainerStyle={{
    height: 100,
    flexDirection: "column",
    alignItems: "stretch",
    marginTop: 16,
  }}
  alwaysBounceVertical={false}
  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the behaviour you are specifying is not what I want. That is, I want to you flex layout. I feel this is a bug in ScrollView's react native implementation. Do you think this is right?

Comment: Not sure I get the difference with the 1st option I suggested. Should the yellow view have a fluid or fixed height?

Comment: The problem with that is the absolute positioning. It was not what I was looking for. Though thanks for your help. I have now figured out the solution. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is to wrap the "green" view in a component like (I am using typescript):

```
class VerticalScrollingContentContainer extends
    React.PureComponent<{style?: Styles},
    {mainViewHeight: number, isMeasured: boolean}> {

constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        mainViewHeight: 0,
        isMeasured: false,
    };
}

layoutReceived = (width: number, height: number) => {
    let newHeight = height > width ? height : width;
    this.setState(
        oldState => ({mainViewHeight: newHeight, isMeasured: true})
    );
}

render() {
    let isMeasured = this.state.isMeasured;
    let mainViewHeight = this.state.mainViewHeight;
    let innerContainerLayout = {
        flexDirection: "column",
    };
    if (!isMeasured) {
        innerContainerLayout = {
            ...innerContainerLayout,
            flex: 1
        };
    } else {
        innerContainerLayout = {
            ...innerContainerLayout,
            minHeight: mainViewHeight
        };
    }
    return (
        <ScrollView
            style={{flex: 1}}
            contentContainerStyle={innerContainerLayout as any}
            alwaysBounceVertical={false}
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
            <View
                style={[
                    {
                        flexGrow: 1,
                        alignItems: "flex-start",
                        flexDirection: "column",
                    },
                    this.props.style
                ]}
                onLayout={(e) => {
                    this.layoutReceived(e.nativeEvent.layout.width, e.nativeEvent.layout.height); }}>
                {this.props.children}
            </View>
        </ScrollView>
    );
}
```

}